# Responsive Grid with fixed size columns

Tags: javascript, css, grid, responsive-design, zurb-foundation

I'm new to the Foundation Framework and just started using it. I'm creating a responsive design using Foundation Grid.

I've created desktop layout Grid with 2x4 (rows, column) grid.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="large-12 columns">
  <div class="row">
```

```
    <div class="large-3 small-6 columns">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/250x250&text=Thumbnail" />
      <h6 class="panel">Description</h6>
    </div>

    <div class="large-3 small-6 columns">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/250x250&text=Thumbnail" />
      <h6 class="panel">Description</h6>
    </div>

    <div class="large-3 small-6 columns">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/250x250&text=Thumbnail" />
      <h6 class="panel">Description</h6>
    </div>

    <div class="large-3 small-6 columns">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/250x250&text=Thumbnail" />
      <h6 class="panel">Description</h6>
    </div>

<!-- End Thumbnails -->

  </div>     
</div>
```

[image: Foundation Grid]

Now, I want is two columns layout for Tablet, and 1 column layout for Mobile. By default grid resizes columns to fill the empty space but I want columns of fixed-size.

[image: Tablet Grid layout]

one solution I can think of is updating the DOM hierarchy based on @media queries using javascript. But I want a better solution, if possible using CSS.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: For these kind of layout transformations `@media queries` were introduced. I think media query is most suitable in your case.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Foundation 4.3+, you can download an additional stylesheet that enables a [medium grid](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/grid.html#medium-grid) in addition to the small and large ones that you're currently using.  While this feature is technically listed as experimental, it's set to become standard with the release of Foundation 5 on November 21st.

Answer (score 0):

Using the @media and certain screen widths (in pixels), you can specify max and min widths so the div will remain fluid, but not go off screen or go smaller than you allow.

You will need to specify widths for most common devices...

eg.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 980px) {
  #your id {max-width:99%; min-width:75%;}
  .image class {width:975px; height:450px;}
}
@media screen and (max-width: 650px) {
  #your id {max-width:99%; min-width:75%;}
  .image class {width:648px; height:290px;}
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  and so on...
}
@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
  and so on...
}
media screen and (max-width: 240px) {
  and lastly...
}
```